# Write to file doesnt work "Indentation error"

Tags: python, python-2.7, pokemon-go

I tried to save some data to a csv file and i got this error:

```
i:\Games\Pokemon GO\pokeminer-0.2>python worker.py -st 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "worker.py", line 25, in <module>
    import db
  File "i:\Games\Pokemon GO\pokeminer-0.2\db.py", line 64
    f = open('i:\Games\Pokemon GO\pokeminer-0.2\spawn_location.csv','w')
                                                                       ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

And this is the code:

```
def add_sighting(session, spawn_id, pokemon):  
obj = Sighting(  
    pokemon_id=pokemon['id'],  
    spawn_id=spawn_id,  
    expire_timestamp=pokemon['disappear_time'],  
    normalized_timestamp=normalize_timestamp(pokemon['disappear_time']),  
    lat=pokemon['lat'],  
    lon=pokemon['lng'],  
)  
# Check if there isn't the same entry already  
existing = session.query(Sighting) \  
    .filter(Sighting.pokemon_id == obj.pokemon_id) \  
    .filter(Sighting.spawn_id == obj.spawn_id) \  
    .filter(Sighting.expire_timestamp > obj.expire_timestamp - 10) \  
    .filter(Sighting.expire_timestamp < obj.expire_timestamp + 10) \  
    .filter(Sighting.lat == obj.lat) \  
    .filter(Sighting.lon == obj.lon) \  
    .first()   
if existing:  
    return  
session.add(obj) 

f = open('i:\Games\Pokemon GO\pokeminer-0.2\spawn_location.csv','w')    
f.write(pokemon_id+lon+lat+expire_timestamp)    
f.close()
```

This code is not mine, i'm just trying to make it write some details to a csv file. Can you please help me out with this, to make it work?

Comment: The code inside the function, after the `def` statement, should be indented.  The code as you show it would never work in Python.  Go back to the person you got the code from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the rest of the code is correct, this should do:

```
def add_sighting(session, spawn_id, pokemon):  
    obj = Sighting(  
        pokemon_id=pokemon['id'],  
        spawn_id=spawn_id,  
        expire_timestamp=pokemon['disappear_time'],
        normalized_timestamp=normalize_timestamp(pokemon['disappear_time']),  
        lat=pokemon['lat'],  
        lon=pokemon['lng'],  
    )  
    # Check if there isn't the same entry already  
    existing = session.query(Sighting) \  
        .filter(Sighting.pokemon_id == obj.pokemon_id) \  
        .filter(Sighting.spawn_id == obj.spawn_id) \  
        .filter(Sighting.expire_timestamp > obj.expire_timestamp - 10)     \
        .filter(Sighting.expire_timestamp < obj.expire_timestamp + 10) \ 
        .filter(Sighting.lat == obj.lat) \  
        .filter(Sighting.lon == obj.lon) \  
        .first()   
    if existing:  
        return  
    session.add(obj) 

    f = open('i:\Games\Pokemon GO\pokeminer-0.2\spawn_location.csv','w')    
    f.write(pokemon_id+lon+lat+expire_timestamp)    
    f.close()
```

That's because Python does not use explicit delimiters to its functions like other languages (e.g. C flavored languages, which use curly braces {}). Instead, Python uses indentation to define where functions start and where they end. `def` is how you start a function, and `add_sighting` is the name of the function. Everything after that is (probably) within the function, and therefore should be indented.